# Replace href value at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have many A html tags in my master web page. I would like to replace their HREF values at runtime using code. How to do that? All a tags are tagged with runat="server".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate over all the controls in the `ControlsCollection` and update the `Href` property of all controls that are of type `HtmlAnchor`, like this:

```
private void UpdateTags(Control page)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in page.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is HtmlAnchor)
            {
                ((HtmlAnchor)ctrl).HRef = "myNewlink";
            }
            else
            {
                if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    UpdateTags(ctrl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.href.aspx) property of AncorTag HTML Control to change it.

like this:

```
<a id="anchor1" runat="server"></a>
```

In code

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    anchor1.HRef = "http://www.microsoft.com";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HtmlAnchor MyAnchor = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("YourAnchorID");
MyAnchor.HRef = "mypage.aspx";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give it an Id and then change the `Href` property.

```
<a runat="server" id="link1">link 1</a>
```

And then:

```
link1.HRef = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a CustomControl, extending the `Hyperlink`-Class and put some Logic into that.
We use it to a custom hyperlink to add Trackingdata to some links.